# How to run multiple migrations on multiple databases in golang-revel

Tags: go, go-gorm, revel

I have a project that use `golang-revel` and use `GORM` to connect to DB. I don't know how to migrate multiple databases. I have successfuly migrate with one database but struggling to migrate more than 1 database

`routes conf`

```
GET     /:db/migrate    App.Migrate
```

`app.go`

```
func (c App) Migrate() revel.Result {
    messages := c.Migration(nil)
    return c.Render(messages)
}
```

`base.go`

```
func (c *BaseController) Migration(tables []interface{}) []string {
    var (
        md       = &m.Model{}
        mh       = &MigrationHelpers{}
        mo       = &m.Module{}
        pr       = &m.Privilege{}
        messages = []string{}
    )

    messages = append(messages, "* Running Auto Migration")

    // Migrate tables
    if tables == nil {
        for i, table := range md.Tables() {
            messages = append(messages, "* Migrating Table "+i)
            if err := c.Txn.AutoMigrate(table).Error; err != nil {
                messages = append(messages, err.Error())
            }
        }
    } else {
        c.Txn.Set("gorm:table_options", "ENGINE=InnoDB").AutoMigrate(tables)
    }
    
    messages = append(messages, "* SCRIPTS AutoMigration Done!")

    // Detect New Modules
    mh.traverseModule(mo.List(c.Controller), c)
    messages = append(messages, "* New MODULES Detection Done!")
    // Detect New Privilege
    mh.traversePrivilege(pr.List(c.Controller), c)
    messages = append(messages, "* New PRIVILEGES Detection Done!")

    for _, message := range messages {
        fmt.Println(message)
    }

    return messages
}
```